# If condition combination in batch file

Tags: batch-file

The following if condition acts as IF NOT DEFINED PARAM_INSERT_DATE_US **AND** IF NOT DEFINED PARAM_UPDATE_DATE_US GOTO END

```
IF NOT DEFINED PARAM_INSERT_DATE_US IF NOT DEFINED PARAM_UPDATE_DATE_US GOTO END
```

Where PARAM_INSERT_DATE_US and PARAM_UPDATE_DATE_US are two variables set at the beginning of batch file.

But I want something similar to this:

```
IF NOT DEFINED PARAM_INSERT_DATE_US OR IF NOT DEFINED PARAM_UPDATE_DATE_US GOTO END
```

Is there a way to achieve it concisely?

Obviously I can break the if statements into 2 to achieve that behavior but I was looking for a concise format as I need to check for 4 variables or more.

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @NPE. But seems like there's no combined way to do what I was looking for :/ .

Answer (score 0):

```
:elsewhere

...

if defined PARAM_INSERT_DATE_US IF DEFINED PARAM_UPDATE_DATE_US goto elsewhere
:end
```

would do the job - arranging the batch that way may be a game...

Answer (score 0):

This will work for the situation you have described.

```
for %%a in (PARAM_INSERT_DATE_US PARAM_UPDATE_DATE_US) do if not defined %%a goto :END
```